# Why flame testing different ions give different colors?

Tags: ions

In my textbook, there was an experiment that described how to flame test different ions and I was just curious why they give off different colors. My knowledge is very basic being just a high school-er, but at what academic level do we learn the reason different ions give off different colors? Would appreciate if someone could explain in a very basic way, if it is possible.

Comment: You can surely search here for more. Each species, atomic, molecular or ionised, has its own electronic structures. Within this structure, only certain jumps are allowed, and they happened at once. Like you go from the first floor to one allowed superior floor without using all the steps of the stair, but in a sort of jumping. The same is valid for the way back to the ground floor. The distance between floors corresponds to an amount energy. Again, now see this energy as carried by one discrete speck of light, surely you know already the word photon... This can be seen as a dose or packet of

Comment: of energy. It turns out that each energy correspond to a colour. That is why each species absorbs or emits characteristic colours. Not sure if this helps or it is too elementary. In all cases it can be useful for a future reader at elementary levels.

Comment: I was sort of able to understand, but the jumping thing still seemed a little advanced, but thanks I now have at least a basic understanding hoping to learn more in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you heat an atom the electrons present in it gets excited by absorbing energy. So it jumps to a higher energy level or shell. And when they return to their original positions they emit a quantum of energy(i.e., a discrete quantity of energy). The wavelength of the emitted light depends on the difference in the two energy levels.

This energy is given by, $$E=(hc)/λ$$ Where $λ$ is the wave length of electromagnetic wave. The released energy is fixed for the orbitals of each element and therefore the wavelength too are unique for every element(and h&c are constants).

This is why different elements give off different colors.

Hope you understand:)